# ¿Como validar la entrada de datos en un input de tipo email que permita solo números, letras y los caracteres punto ("."), guion ("-") y piso ("_")?

Tags: javascript

El campo correo debe:

1. Solo Mayúsculas
2. Aceptar solo este tipo de caracteres especiales por teclado  punto ("."), guion ("-") y piso ("_").
3. Formato valido Ej: ejemplocorreo@domain.???

Comment: Tú "pregunta" la estoy entendiendo como: "Haz el trabajo por mi".

Comment: ¿Podríamos ver el código de los intentos que has realizado y por qué no te funcionan?

Comment: Pásate, por ejemplo, por esta web: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar los inputs de HTML5 que te permiten incluir expresiones regulares en la etiqueta 'pattern':

```
<input type="text" name="mi_campo" 
pattern="AQUÍ TU EXPRESIÓN REGULAR" />
```

Comment: Exacto, pero creo que me exprese mal al principio necesito es la expresión regular ya que es hipercomplicada de entender...

Comment: Para validar que sólo se introducen números, letras, guiones y puntos, la expresión sería algo parecido a ' [a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]+ '.

Las expresiones regulares son dificiles de entender, pero tienes páginas como https://regex101.com/ que son perfectas para aprender y pelearse con ellas.